# How can I configure my prod env vars when I run my build process?

Tags: reactjs, npm, environment-variables, npm-scripts

I'm building a React 16.13.0 application.  I want to configure an endpoint differently, per environment, so I have set this up in a component, src/containers/FormContainer.jsx, ...

```
class FormContainer extends Component {
  static DEFAULT_COUNTRY = 484
  static REACT_APP_PROXY = process.env.REACT_APP_PROXY
    ...
```

I want to build my project for production locally.  However locally I have defined this variable

```
localhost:client davea$ echo $REACT_APP_PROXY
http://localhost:9090
```

and after I run "npm run-script build," I notice this compiled into my build files ...

```
(function(e){return e.json()})).then((function(t){console.log(t),n=t.map((function(e){return e})),e.setState({provinces:n})}))}}]),t}(n.Component);S.DEFAULT_COUNTRY=484,S.REACT_APP_PROXY="http://localhost:9090"
```

Is there any way to not get React to auto-resolve the env var and instead grab it from the production environment?  Maybe I need to adjust my build script?  Below is what's defined in my package.json file ...

```
localhost:client davea$ cat package.json 
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "jquery": "^1.9.1",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.17",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.1.15",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8000",
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: In the production environment the JS is running in *your users' browsers*, it has no access to environment variables set on their machine. What you deploy from that build are just static HTML, CSS and JS files.

Comment: Oh right, so when people are building React applications for production are they always building them on the production machine from which the application will be served?

Comment: Ideally they're building them in a clean CI environment. I don't think the build-time configuration options like setting REACT_APP_ env vars or Angular's [environment](https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-application-environments) feature are particularly useful; they mean you have to create a separate build for each environment you want to deploy to. Instead aim to have a *single, known-good asset* that you can actually promote between environments.

Comment: What strategy would you recommend for setting different endpoints (env vars for lack of a better word) per enivonrment?

Comment: There are several ways. [Here's](https://timysewyn.be/blog/2017-12-27-Deploying-web-applications-with-environment-specific-configurations/) one my colleague wrote up. I've also used server-side includes for this, or just swapped out a specific JS file that's excluded from the bundling. You can also avoid the need entirely using service discovery patterns or relative routing (using a reverse proxy or something like Cloud Foundry's [path routing](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/routes-domains.html#-create-an-http-route-with-a-path)).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using react-scripts to build your App. You can define environment variables in your .env files.

For variables that are common across your node environment, you can define them in .env file

For variable that are specific to `development` and `production`, you can define them in `.env.development` and `.env.production` files

Also please prefix your variables with `REACT_APP`

Once you do that you can add scripts in your package.json to specify a build for a particular `NODE_ENV`

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=development react-scripts build",
    "build:prod": "NODE_ENV=production react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

and then you can build your APP for production locally like

```
yarn run build:prod
```

and it will use the production environment variables

Read more about it on create react app [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)

Comment: Does this actually work in the example given for NODE_ENV? I was under the impression the devs were highly opinionated about that particular variable and don't let it be manually overridden like this:  https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Comment: @JoeHolloway is right, you cannot override `NODE_ENV` manually like this.

Answer (score 4):

**The following steps may help. Try it:**

> You can also refer to the original documents for more information:
>
> [Adding Custom Environment Variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)

**First Step:**

Create `.env` file in the root of project

Project structure after making the `.env` file:

```
...
- build
- public
- src
    |----- App.js
    |----- index.js
- package.json
- .env
...
```

**Inside of `.env` file:(for example) Prefix `REACT_APP_` is required!**

```
REACT_APP_URL_DEVELOPMENT=http://localhost:8000/api
REACT_APP_URL_PRODUCTION=https://productionDomain.com/api/
```

**Second Step:**

**package.json file:**

`Scripts` No need to change in `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "http://myWebsite.com",
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Third Step:**

Finally, you can conditionally use the variables you created.

**Example:**

```
class Posts extends Component{
    ...

    componentDidMount(){

      // Finally, you can conditionally use the variables you created.
      const url = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? process.env.REACT_APP_URL_DEVELOPMENT : process.env.REACT_APP_URL_PRODUCTION;

      axios.get(url)
        .then(res => { ... })
        .catch(err => { ... });

    }

    render(){
      return(
        ...
      )
    }
}
```

**Faqs section:**

> `process.env` is a global Object provided by your environment through
>   NodeJs. Because we don't have NodeJS in browser. But you can access to `NODE_ENV` by init your app using `create-react-app` with `webpack` included by default and perform the above steps. More details below:

There is a built-in environment variable called `NODE_ENV`. You can access it from `process.env.NODE_ENV`. This variable changes based on what mode you are currently in. When you run `npm start`, it is equal to `development`, when you run `npm test` it is equal to `test`, and when you run `npm run build` it is equal to `production`. This variable is special as it can be used to access different environment configurations based on your mode.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else having this problem, but unsuccessful with the accepted answer try this.

1. Install [env-cmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd)
2. In your package.json, set the env in your build command like so: `"build:staging": "env-cmd -f .env.<ENV_NAME> react-scripts build",`

Note, make sure a file called `.env.<ENV_NAME>` exists in the root of your project

Answer (score 1):

try

```
yarn build --mode your_env
```

Answer (score 0):

install '**env-cmd**' package

`npm install --save-dev env-cmd`

Update **package.json**

```js
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start:local": "env-cmd -f .env.local react-scripts start",
    "build:local": "env-cmd -f .env.local react-scripts build"
    "start:stage": "env-cmd -f .env.stage react-scripts start",
    "build:stage": "env-cmd -f .env.stage react-scripts build"
    "start:live": "env-cmd -f .env.live react-scripts start",
    "build:live": "env-cmd -f .env.live react-scripts build"
  },
```

Run start or build as you want environment by

```js
 // Local environment
 npm run start:local
 npm run build:local
 
 // Stage environment
 npm run start:local
 npm run build:local
 
 // Live environment
 npm run start:live
 npm run build:live
```